# Mapping an array of strings to results in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I've got this JSON string

```
{"plaats":["Rottevalle","Rotterdam"]}
```

And I like to get "Rottevalle and Rotterdam" as an item in my selectbox with Select2

I've got this code.

```
$("#plaats").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: 'plaatsen.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                    return { id: obj.plaats, text: obj.plaats };
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Problem is that I don't understand how I get the `plaats` data back within `processResults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the full response into `$.map` instead of the `plaats` key of that.

```
$("#plaats").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: 'plaatsen.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data.plaats, function(obj) {
                    return { id: obj, text: obj };
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```